# php gd image png watermark on jpg file produces weird result

Tags: php, gd, libpng

Trying to add a transparent PNG watermark to jpg images get's me different results either if i'm on localhost or production server.

Here's the results...

On my localhost (PHP Version 5.6.24)
[image]

On production server (PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21)
[image]

I don't even know what to call this problem of the blue color turning pink and the logo doesn't get correctly rendered...

**The code is this:**

```
function getBrightness($gdHandle) {
$width = imagesx($gdHandle);
$height = imagesy($gdHandle);

$totalBrightness = 0;

for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
        $rgb = imagecolorat($gdHandle, $x, $y);

        $red = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $green = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $blue = $rgb & 0xFF;

        $totalBrightness += (max($red, $green, $blue) + min($red, $green, $blue)) / 2;
    }
}

  //  imagedestroy($gdHandle);

return ($totalBrightness / ($width * $height)) / 2.55;
}

function render_text_on_gd_image(&$source_gd_image, $text, $font, $size, $color, $opacity, $rotation, $bpx, $bpy, $wnewx) {

$source_width = imagesx($source_gd_image);
$source_height = imagesy($source_gd_image);
$bb = imagettfbbox($size, $rotation, $font, $text);
$x0 = min($bb[0], $bb[2], $bb[4], $bb[6]);
$x1 = max($bb[0], $bb[2], $bb[4], $bb[6]);
$y0 = min($bb[1], $bb[3], $bb[5], $bb[7]);
$y1 = max($bb[1], $bb[3], $bb[5], $bb[7]);
$bb_width = abs($x1 - $x0);
$bb_height = abs($y1 - $y0);

$alpha_color = imagecolorallocatealpha(
    $source_gd_image,
    hexdec(substr($color, 0, 2)),
    hexdec(substr($color, 2, 2)),
    hexdec(substr($color, 4, 2)),
    127 * (100 - $opacity) / 100
);
return imagettftext($source_gd_image, $size, $rotation, $bpx + $wnewx/2 - $bb_width/2 , $bpy, $alpha_color, $font, $text);
}


$val = array();

//$val["displayName"] = "Administrador";
$val["displayName"] = "Afonso Ferreira Gomes";

$val["relFile"] = "imagem.jpg";

list($val["width_original"], $val["height_original"]) = getimagesize($val["relFile"]);

if ($val["width_original"] > $val["height_original"] && $val["width_original"] >= 1200) {

    $val["height_resized"] = $val["height_original"] * (1200/$val["width_original"]);
    $val["width_resized"]  = 1200;

}  elseif ($val["height_original"] > $val["width_original"] && $val["height_original"] >= 1200) {

    $val["height_resized"] = 1200;
    $val["width_resized"]  = (1200/$val["height_original"]) * $val["width_original"];

} else {

    $val["height_resized"] = $val["height_original"];
    $val["width_resized"]  = $val["width_original"];

}

$i = imagecreatefromjpeg($val["relFile"]);

$i = imagescale($i, $val["width_resized"], $val["height_resized"]);

$val["width_new"] = imagesx($i);

$val["height_new"] = imagesy($i);


if ($val["width_new"] < $val["height_new"]) {

    $val["portait"] = true;
    $val["smallest"] = $val["width_new"];

} else {

    $val["portait"] = false;
    $val["smallest"] = $val["height_new"];

}


/* GERAR WATERMARK LOGOTIPO */
$val["racio"] = 0.20;
$val["marLeft"] = 40;
$val["marBottom"] = 40;
$val["bright"] = getBrightness($i);


if ($val["bright"] < 30) {

    $val["opacidade"] = 20;

} else {

    $val["opacidade"] = 40;

}

$w = imagecreatefrompng("jbw_260_40.png");

if ($val["portait"]) {

    $val["water_width"] = $val["width_new"] * $val["racio"];
    $val["water_height"] = $val["width_new"] * $val["racio"];

} else {

    $val["water_width"] = $val["height_new"] * $val["racio"];
    $val["water_height"] = $val["height_new"] * $val["racio"];

}

$wnew = imagescale($w, $val["water_width"], $val["water_height"]);

$val["water_width"] = imagesx($wnew);
$val["water_height"] = imagesy($wnew);

/* GERAR WATERMARK TEXTO AUTOR */
if ($val["displayName"] == "Administrador") {
    $val["autor"] = "";
    $val["marBottom"] = 20;
    $val["marLeft"] = 20;
} else {
    $val["autor"] = $val["displayName"];
}


// PRIMEIRO E ULTIMO NOME SÓ!!
$autorNomes = explode(" ", $val["autor"]);

if (count($autorNomes) >= 2) {
    $val["autor"] = $autorNomes[0] . " " . $autorNomes[count($autorNomes) - 1];
} else {
    $val["autor"] = $autorNomes[0];
}

$font = "../font/Montserrat.ttf";
$color = "FFFFFF";

$flagSize = false;

$val["fontSize"] = 12;

for ($size = 7; $size <= 50; $size += 0.5) {

    $bb = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $val["autor"]);
    $x0 = min($bb[0], $bb[2], $bb[4], $bb[6]);
    $x1 = max($bb[0], $bb[2], $bb[4], $bb[6]);
    $y0 = min($bb[1], $bb[3], $bb[5], $bb[7]);
    $y1 = max($bb[1], $bb[3], $bb[5], $bb[7]);

    $val["bbox_width"] = abs($x1 - $x0);
    $val["bbox_height"] = abs($y1 - $y0);

    if (($val["bbox_width"] >= $val["water_width"] && !$flagSize) || $size == 50) {
        $val["fontSize"] = $size;
        $flagSize = true;
        break;
    }
}

$val["posY_water"] = $val["height_new"] - $val["water_height"] - $val["marBottom"];
$val["posY_text"] = $val["height_new"] - $val["marBottom"] + $val["bbox_height"] - 5;

imagecopy($i, $wnew, $val["marLeft"],  $val["posY_water"] , 0, 0, $val["water_width"], $val["water_height"]);

render_text_on_gd_image($i, $val["autor"], $font, $val["fontSize"], $color, $val["opacidade"] ,0 , $val["marLeft"]  , $val["posY_text"], $val["water_width"]);


// echo "<pre>"; print_r($val); echo "</pre>"; die;

/* OUTPUT IMAGEM E LIMPA BUFFER */
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($i);
imagedestroy($i);
imagedestroy($w);
```

**And this are the gd section of phpinfo for localhost and production server**
[image]

What am I missing? this is driving me insane!

Comment: Could it be the difference in version of the `libpng` library causing the problem? Since the localhost version is 9 and the server version is 8. Maybe try an update?

Comment: I'm no expert but I think most probably is and I can't change anything on server's php or libpng...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those issues almost always object to the alpha channel of either the source or destination not beeing preserved or the output not really beeing true color.

Try using the `imagesavealpha()` function and search for `"alpha"` in the comments of the PHP documentation because there are many people having solutions to similiar issues.

This comment might be helpful and is kinda what Esko said:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php#90364

Basically it copies an image to a buffer using `imagecreatetruecolor()`.

Comment: With GD I'm not on my beach so please bare with me. :) So what you're saying is: instead of opening jpeg and work on it, I should create a new image with imagetruecolor() and then pass to that one the original image and the watermark while using the imagesavealpha() ?

Comment: @AfonsoGomes yes just like that! During opening and saving, some information from the picture gets lost and there are little differences between library versions.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same issue. The imageScale function in Ubuntu seems to turn greens and blues to pink. Solution could be to use imagecopyresampled and imagecreatetruecolor. However this solution is way slower.

Comment: The imageScale issue seems to me to be a different ball game! I had issues with that one too. It won't work correctly if you only feed it the width... that's why on my code I pass the width and the height. Don't know what you have on your code but that did the trick for me.